# fail2ban on Ubuntu (defaults okay?)

Tags: ubuntu, security, debian, firewall, fail2ban

I run an Ubuntu-based web-server (LAMP) and have installed fail2ban. Does it have sensible defaults to restrict malicious activity via SSH and any LAMP ports out-of-the-box? Or, does it need to be configured?

Note: I also use iptables firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common for the defaults in packages from a standard repository to have reasonable defaults, but it is *always* advisable to review the configuration files to make sure they options selected are suitable. Sometimes you'll need to do this with reference to the upstream documentation, but sometimes you'll find that the default file has copious comments which may be enough on their own.